# Add a class to the first section after a specific div, with jQuery

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<header id="header" class="">
    <div class="header-top-row">

Some fancy code.        

    </div>
</header>

<style>
Some fancy styles.
</style>

<section>
</section>

<section>
</section>

<section>
</section>
```

How can I add a class with jquery to the first section after the header?

Comment: `$('header').siblings('section:first')`.....??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('header ~ section:first').addClass('test');
```

```css
.test{
  color:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header" class="">
    <div class="header-top-row">

Some fancy code.        

    </div>
</header>

<style>
Some fancy styles.
</style>

<section>
  section
</section>

<section>
  section
</section>

<section>
   section
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
$('header').siblings('section:first').css('background', '#e4e4e4');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>prepend demo</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
 $( "body section" ).first().addClass('test');
})
</script>

</style>

</head>
<body>
<section>
</section>
<section>
</section>

</body>
```